# Сделать скругленные края для QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt6

Имеется проблема, что стили (на барьер) не применяются для главного виджета QMainWindow - конкретно

```css
border: 1px solid black; 
border-radius: 10px;
```

Хочу сделать что-то подобно такое:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но выходит почему-то так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я не так делаю?

Да и возможно ли это c использованием QSS? Если нет, то не особо понимаю, как тогда реализовать кодом на плюсах..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищя вопрос на данный ответ, я понял что в итоге, это невозможно сделать с помощью QSS для окон верхнего уровня типа MainWindow.

За пределами таких пользовательских окон на самом деле невозможно изменить внешний вид Windows, поскольку этим управляет операционная система. Не Qt.

**Чтобы решить данную проблему, воспользуйтесь QPainterPath и маской для создания скругленных углов:**

```cpp
    QPainterPath painPath;
    painPath.addRoundedRect(rect(), 8, 8, Qt::AbsoluteSize);
    this->setMask(painPath.toFillPolygon().toPolygon());
```

**P.S Более сглаженные углы с помощью QPainther:**

```cpp
    QPainter pain;
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); // Ставим прозрачный фон 
    pain.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    pain.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    pain.drawRoundedRect(rect(), 8, 8, Qt::AbsoluteSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать как я. Поставить QFrame или любой другой виджет с закруглёнными через QSS краями как фон, а QMainWindow сделать прозрачным.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]